How can I load data in Rstudio but making it accessible in other computers when opening the file?
I'm working on an assignment and we were asked to load the data and make the file run without errors when opening from the teacher's computer. He said: "When writing your code, keep the data files in the same directory as your notebook so that you DO NOT specify directories or file paths in your code. This allows us to run your code smoothly on our device."
How can I make sure it works on other computers smoothely?
I did read.csv but how can this work if I uploaded only the Rmd file?

If you create a new "Project" in RStudio and create your script files within that project, you should be able to share/upload the project folder/files and have them run smoothly on another device. https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-RStudio-Projects

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/vignettes/here.html and https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/
